# Is there something in Python that is similar to Harmony's let keyword?

Tags: javascript, python

In Harmony, there is a `let` keyword that allows for declaration of variables that are scoped to the nearest block. For example

```
function foo() {
    if (true){
        let a = 100;
    }
    return a
}
```

will result in an error since `a` is only defined inside the `if` block.

I know I can use `del` to achieve the same thing, but that that is manual instead of automatic like the `let` keyword

Answer (score 2):

Python creates scopes for every class, module, function or generator expression. There is no scoping within blocks of code. You might be able to achieve your intended goal using nested functions, e.g.:

```
def outside():
    def inside():
        var=5
    print var
```

Calling outside will result in:

```
outside()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 5, in outside
NameError: global name 'var' is not defined
```